# Loaded glibc base address different for each function

Tags: linux, reverse-engineering, glibc, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to calculate the base address of the library of a binary file.
I have the address of printf, puts ecc and then I subtract it's offset to get the base address of the library.
I was doing this for printf, puts and signal, but every time I got a different base address.
I also tried to do the things in [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1994/base-address-of-shared-objects-from-ldd-output) post, but I couldn't get the right result either.

ASLR is disabled.

this is where I take the address of the library function:

```
gdb-peda$ x/20wx 0x804b018
0x804b018 <signal@got.plt>:     0xf7e05720      0xf7e97010      0x080484e6      0x080484f6
0x804b028 <puts@got.plt>:       0xf7e3fb40      0x08048516      0x08048526      0xf7df0d90
0x804b038 <memset@got.plt>:     0xf7f18730      0x08048556      0x08048566      0x00000000
```

then I have:

```
gdb-peda$ info proc mapping
process 114562
Mapped address spaces:

        Start Addr   End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
         0x8048000  0x804a000     0x2000        0x0 /home/ofey/CTF/Pwnable.tw/applestore/applestore
         0x804a000  0x804b000     0x1000     0x1000 /home/ofey/CTF/Pwnable.tw/applestore/applestore
         0x804b000  0x804c000     0x1000     0x2000 /home/ofey/CTF/Pwnable.tw/applestore/applestore
         0x804c000  0x806e000    0x22000        0x0 [heap]
        0xf7dd8000 0xf7fad000   0x1d5000        0x0 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
        0xf7fad000 0xf7fae000     0x1000   0x1d5000 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
        0xf7fae000 0xf7fb0000     0x2000   0x1d5000 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
        0xf7fb0000 0xf7fb1000     0x1000   0x1d7000 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
        0xf7fb1000 0xf7fb4000     0x3000        0x0
        0xf7fd0000 0xf7fd2000     0x2000        0x0
        0xf7fd2000 0xf7fd5000     0x3000        0x0 [vvar]
        0xf7fd5000 0xf7fd6000     0x1000        0x0 [vdso]
        0xf7fd6000 0xf7ffc000    0x26000        0x0 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
        0xf7ffc000 0xf7ffd000     0x1000    0x25000 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
        0xf7ffd000 0xf7ffe000     0x1000    0x26000 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
        0xfffdd000 0xffffe000    0x21000        0x0 [stack]
```

and :

```
gdb-peda$ info sharedlibrary
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0xf7fd6ab0  0xf7ff17fb  Yes         /lib/ld-linux.so.2
0xf7df0610  0xf7f3d386  Yes         /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

I then found the offset of signal and puts to calculate the base libc address.

```
base_with_signal_offset = 0xf7e05720 - 0x3eda0 =  0xf7dc6980
base_with_puts_offset = 0xf7e3fb40 - 0x809c0 = 0xf7dbf180
```

I was expecting `base_with_signal_offset = base_with_puts_offset = 0xf7dd8000`, but that's not the case.
What I'm doing wrong? 
EDIT(To let you understand where I got those offset):

```
readelf -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so  | grep puts
```

I get :

```
    191: 00000000000809c0   512 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _IO_puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5
   422: 00000000000809c0   512 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   13 puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5
   496: 00000000001266c0  1240 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 putspent@@GLIBC_2.2.5
   678: 00000000001285d0   750 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 putsgent@@GLIBC_2.10
  1141: 000000000007f1f0   396 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   13 fputs@@GLIBC_2.2.5
  1677: 000000000007f1f0   396 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _IO_fputs@@GLIBC_2.2.5
  2310: 000000000008a640   143 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   13 fputs_unlocked@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

Comment: You are subtracting effectively random numbers. I can see where `0xf7e05720 ` and `0xf7e3fb40 ` came from (they are the wrong numbers to use), but have no idea where `0x3eda0 ` and `0x809c0 ` came from. Please edit your question to show the origin of the last two.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I hope that now is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was expecting base_with_signal_offset = base_with_puts_offset = 0xf7dd8000

There are 3 numbers in your calculation:

```
&puts_at_runtime - symbol_value_from_readelf == &first_executable_pt_load_segment_libc.
```

The `readelf` output shows that you got one of these *almost* correct: the value of `puts` in 64-bit `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so` is indeed `0x809c0`, but that is *not* the library you are actually using. You need to repeat the same on the *actually used* 32-bit library: `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so`.

For the first number -- &puts_at_runtime, you are using value from the `puts@got.plt` import stub. That value is only guaranteed to have been resolved (point to actual `puts` in `libc.so`) IFF you have `LD_BIND_NOW=1` set in the environment, or you linked your executable with `-z now` linker flag, or you actually called `puts` already.

It may be better to `print &puts` in GDB.

The last number -- &first_executable_pt_load_segment_libc is correct (because `info shared` shows that `libc.so.6` `.text` section starts at `0xf7df0610`, which is between `0xf7dd8000` and `0xf7fad000`.

So putting it all together, the only error was that you used the wrong version of `libc.so` to extract the symbol_value_from_readelf.

On my system:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  puts("Hello");
  signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
  return 0;
}
```

```
gcc -m32 t.c  -fno-pie -no-pie
```

```
gdb -q a.out
... set breakpoint on exit from main
Breakpoint 1, 0x080491ae in main ()
(gdb) p &puts
$1 = (<text variable, no debug info> *) 0xf7e31300 <puts>
(gdb) p &signal
$2 = (<text variable, no debug info> *) 0xf7df7d20 <ssignal>
(gdb) info proc map
process 114065
Mapped address spaces:

    Start Addr   End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
     0x8048000  0x8049000     0x1000        0x0 /tmp/a.out
     ...
     0x804d000  0x806f000    0x22000        0x0 [heap]
    0xf7dc5000 0xf7de2000    0x1d000        0x0 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.29.so
    ...
(gdb) info shared
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0xf7fd5090  0xf7ff0553  Yes (*)     /lib/ld-linux.so.2
0xf7de20e0  0xf7f2b8d6  Yes (*)     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Given above, we expect `readelf -s` to give us `0xf7e31300 - 0xf7dc5000 == 
0x6c300` for `puts` and `0xf7df7d20 - 0xf7dc5000 == 0x32d20` for `signal` respectively.

```
readelf -Ws /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.29.so | egrep ' (puts|signal)\W'
   452: 00032d20    68 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   14 signal@@GLIBC_2.0
   458: 0006c300   400 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   14 puts@@GLIBC_2.0
```

QED.

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck on this for 2 days and it was just a distraction error. Running `print &puts` got me the same address of before (0xf7e3fb40), instead running `info func puts` got me a list of things (like File iofputs_u.c: .....) and at the end Non-debugging symbols: 0x0848500 puts@plt I don't know about this last thing but I think that my way to get the address of puts is correct. The segment seems to be correct but `readelf -Wl /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so | grep PT_LOAD`  doesn't show anything. `info shared` and ` info proc mapping` came from the same run.

Comment: I don't know why `info shared` got me those address.

Comment: I have a file called libc_32.so.6 in the same folder of the binary but I don't think that this could be the cause of that.